# MDADM - Stop Resync and Force Clean - Possible and/or Safe?

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

I have been having issues with my FileServer recently.

See [“rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks” - jiffies - ESXi Ubuntu 16 FileServer Guest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429865/rcu-sched-detected-stalls-on-cpus-tasks-jiffies-esxi-ubuntu-16-fileserver)

I just rebuilt it since I couldn't get any guidance on the issue. Unfortunatley, its resyncing my array again.

Seeing how this has been done multiple time in the last few days, I'm fairly confident that its "in sync".

I have a few questions to that regard.

- When it resync's what is happening, is it just doing read operations on every piece of data? I feel i'm really abusing my HDD's at the moment
- Can I cancel resync? (I still want to be able to use the MDADM Though!)
- So Can I force it to "clean" state and remount?
- Is resync automatic when you mount a new MDADM (This is a new VM), or is there an error in the metadata that is forcing a resync and I NEED to let it finish. (It takes about 24 Hours and my server is extremely slow during that time)

Thanks!

Update: There are 4x 5tb HDDs in raid5 passed through via mapped raw lun to a VM guest which then exports nfs and smb.

This question is mostly about if the commands i want exist for mdadm and what sync does.

Comment: I'm not saying it's unusual for a VM to have multiple "disks" (e.g. give it a virtual disk for boot/OS and one or more virtual disks disks for data storage), just unusual for the VM to manage its own RAID.

Comment: anything in the kernel logs indicating problems with either the disk controller or any of the drives?

Comment: Esxi doesnt support software raid or being an nfs/smb server

Comment: then why use esxi rather than kvm?

Comment: I think these questions are better posted on my question that I linked. This question is purely about mdadm, it doesn't make a difference that it's a VM.

Comment: @cas I couldn't pass through my Wi-Fi PCI Nic with KVM

Comment: It **does** make a difference that it's a VM.  There's an entire layer of virtualisation added.  Whether that's the cause of your problem or not, I can't tell - but a VM isn't the same as a physical machine because it doesn't have direct access to the hardware.

Comment: just noticed your wifi nic comment - do you need it to be pass-through or is setting it up in the host and using it in the VM via either NAT or bridging good enough.  There aren't many use-cases where a VM needs exclusive and direct access to a NIC.

Comment: It needs pass through for Bluetooth access >> see https://serverfault.com/q/899788/312793

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop a "parity check" as even though all the data is there, mdadm's metadata isn't correct. You have to let it finish.

Side Note: If you are having this issue repeatedly look into hardware failures as the culprit and solve asap!